# Cannot edit ".gitignore" due to strange errors and read-only switched on

Tags: git, read-only-mode

A new error has occurred with a recent upgrade to Emacs 27.1. I'm trying to edit .gitignore and get the following error:

```
*ERROR*: Unlocking file: Invalid argument, <directory>/.gitignore
```

To check this is not an error in an initialisation file, I tried with `emacs -q .gitignore`. However, in this case the file is set to read-only and cannot be edited, and the strange error

```
File exists, but cannot be read
```

appears, then the file appears but as read-only. It doesn't seem to be possible to change to non-read only. To surmount this problem I have taken to renaming .gitignore to another file name then moving that using the `mv` command. The file itself is not read-only:

```
$ ls -l .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 ben  ben  843 Sep  4 07:20 .gitignore
```

Comment: I get the same error with emacs 27.1 on fc32. Also get it for a self-compiled emacs 28.

Comment: Furthermore with a compiled version of 26.3 this doesn't occur

Comment: I'm seeing the problem in only one directory and not in others where I try to edit .gitignore.

Comment: Is this directory on a different type of filesystem than the others? There were changes in emacs-27 to the handling of file-system errors that might be responsible.

Comment: @rpluim - no, the file system is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does setting `(setq create-lockfiles nil)` in your configuration make the error go away? I ask because it appears to me that Emacs is getting the error when it tries to create or open or read from the lock file. The filename of the lock file will be `.#.gitignore`; you should investigate why it can't read or create this particular lock file while others work fine.

Chapter [18.3.4 Protection against Simultaneous Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking) of the Emacs manual covers how Emacs uses the lock file.

Comment: There was a file called `.#.gitignore` in the directory which was an "unreadable symlink" according to the Unix `file` utility. Removing that made `.gitignore` editable.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing appeared to me (on another file). Here is the solution I found:

- Open the file: emacs yourfile.txt
- While it's open, delete the lock file: rm .#yourfile.txt
- Toggle the read-only flag '%' at the bottom of your buffer if needed
- Save it and you are done